# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' with Webpack + TypeScript + React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I configured my simple webapp to build and run a WDS with TypeScript + React. It builds and shows the page properly.

Then, I am trying to add Redux and when I do a simple thing like importing `useDispatch` and trying to call it from my functional component, it builds but shows the error in browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

The code is:

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const MyView = () =>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    ...
}
```

And the page shows nothing.

When I look into the source of the error, I see it's definitely not good because tries to access `{...}.somValue` which should be something like `({...}).somValue` to not cause the error.

[image: Syntax error]

Is it something I can fix by changing webpack config? I only use ts-loader, without any babel stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I had a wrong value in webpack config file, or at least removing it helped:

Was `mode: "none"`

I just removed the whole key and value and it worked.